# Bootstrap nested rows and 2 columns not aligned in equal height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, nested

Hi I have searched everyone for a solution to this but to no avail. I am currently using bootstrap and I have a 1 row, 2 columns with the right column having 2 nested rows. I have 1 big image on the left, with 2 smaller images on the right but for some reason my big image don't align properly with the right column. I have tried flexbox, display: table, nothing works. When it hits the breakpoint for mobile view, it aligns properly (100% width) x3 but for slightly bigger screens it just messes up. Appreciate it if anyone can help! Thank you so much. This is the code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/832x532">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12"><img src="http://placehold.it/513x294"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12"><img src="http://placehold.it/513x294"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/mPLPUTYsUc)

Edit:
It is supposed to look like:

```
[           ] [Image 2 ]
[   Image 1 ] [        ]
[           ] [Image 3 ]
[           ] [        ]
```

Both columns should be of equal height. Right now in the bootply I provided, the first column is shorter than the second column.

Comment: Sorry, I have editted it. Should look better now

Comment: What is this **supposed** to look like?

Comment: So something like this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ONzeyb

Comment: Thank you for replying. There are still spaces at the top and bottom of the left column. I want both columns to be of equal height.

Comment: Oh just remove the align items... That should do it.

Comment: Nope.. left column aligned to the top but there are still spaces at the bottom

Comment: Here try it now - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ONzeyb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution to use `display: flex` to `row` and nested columns, which you want would be an equal height. But, instead to override Bootstrap's class, it's better, to create your own class and to use it in this case.

```
<div class="row equal">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   // content
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    // content
  </div>
</div>

.equal,
.equal > div[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
}
```

I created example with your code and used cross-browser solution

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/e94c6x78/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However, according to https://jsfiddle.net/e94c6x78/1/ I tried to enter my own placeholder width and added some styles to my image it still achieves the same results. This time, the second column is shorter than the other.

Comment: @loveprogramming, because you apply `max-width: 100%` property for all images!